# how to access data from page.svelte in layout.svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

/some-route/page.svelte

```
export let name='John'
```

/layout.svelte

```
{name}  //error name is not defined

<script>
  ???
</script>
```

cant find any working example. in documentation only found with $page.data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not supposed to. A layout can contain various pages, the data is not guaranteed to be the same. If the data is meant for the layout, move it there.

---

Example of communicating with layout via context:

```html
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';

    const errors = writable([]);
    setContext('errors', errors);
</script>

{#each $errors as error}
    <div class="error">{error}</div>
{/each}
<slot />
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    const errors = getContext('errors');
</script>

<button on:click={() => $errors = [...$errors, 'oh no!']}>
    Add error
</button>
```

Comment: in my case, its an error notification (user still can interact with page). this error type originates in some pages and needs to be show at layout (its subdirectory not root). how can I trigger this notification?

Comment: Send an event or [define a context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) that can be interacted with.

Comment: Added an example for using a context.